# Install Ckeditor and ResponsiveFileMenager on website

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor

I have many CKEditor editors on your website and the following code:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="content_pl"></textarea>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="content_en"></textarea>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="content_es"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".ckeditor").each(function () {
            var el = $(this)[0];
            var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[el.id];
            if (instance) { instance.destroy(true); }      
            CKEDITOR.replace(el, {
                filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'http://localhost/responsive_filemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
                filebrowserUploadUrl: 'http://localhost/responsive_filemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
                filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'http://localhost/responsive_filemanager/filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&editor=ckeditor&fldr='
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

ResponsiveFileManager components do not work (they do not add to CKEditor). At the moment when I have only 1 ckeditor - then it's ok. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
It loops through every element with `classname` ckeditor.
Then it get its **Unique** ID (it needs one to identify each CKeditor).
So add an ID to each textarea first.
Then it replaces your textarea with the ckeditor.

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea class="ckeditor" name="content_pl" id="input1"></textarea>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="content_en" id="input2"></textarea>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="content_es" id="input3"></textarea>

<script>
$(".ckeditor").each(function () {
        CKEDITOR.replace( $(this).attr('id'), {
            // Define the toolbar groups as it is a more accessible solution.
            toolbarGroups: [ // you can change this with your code
                 {"name":"basicstyles","groups":["basicstyles"]},
                 {"name":"links","groups":["links"]},
                 {"name":"paragraph","groups":["list"]},
                 {"name":"insert","groups":["insert"]},
                 {"name":"styles","groups":["styles"]}
             ]
         });
});
</script>
```